# how can you loop through all fields of an anonymous type

Tags: c#, field, anonymous-types

i want to take a list of anonymous types and export then to excel.  I have the code to export to excel if i have the data, but i want to be able write some generic code to:

Loop through all of the fields in the anonymous type so i can export it to excel.  I would like to keep the ordering if possible as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I happen to have some code which does almost exactly that...

The ordering of properties isn't guaranteed via reflection, but the *constructor parameters* are. So you can fetch the names via the constructor parameters, and then fetch the properties from there.

Here's a [blog post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/12/09/quot-magic-quot-null-argument-testing.aspx) which uses anonymous types for nullity checks... but basically you'd do the same steps as this bit in the middle, but fetching the values instead. Note that I use a generic class to let me do the reflection bit just once - after that I've got delegates to fetch the values, and a list of names.